# Why is $\operatorname{nilrad} R_S=\left(\operatorname{nilrad} R\right)_S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ a multiplicatively closed set. Let $R_S$ be the localization of $R$ at $S$.

Why is $$\operatorname{nilrad} R_S=\left(\operatorname{nilrad} R\right)_S ?$$

Recall that $\operatorname{nilrad} R$ is the set of nilpotent elements of $R$.

Comment: Some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) (e.g. what book you are reading, any thoughts on the problem) would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I = \textrm{nil}(R) = \{ x \in R : x^n = 0 \textrm{ for some } n \geq 1\}$.  We want to show $\textrm{nil}(S^{-1}R) = S^{-1}I$, where the right hand side is the ideal in $S^{-1}R$ generated by the image of $I$ in $S^{-1}R$.  It is equal to the set of fractions $\frac{a}{s}$, where $a \in I$ and $s \in S$.

Let $\frac{a}{s} \in S^{-1}I$ for some $a \in I$ and $s \in S$.  Since $a$ is nilpotent, it is obvious that $\frac{a}{s}$ is nilpotent.

Conversely suppose that $\frac{r}{s} \in S^{-1}R$ is nilpotent, say $(\frac{r}{s})^n = \frac{r^n}{s^n}$ is zero in $S^{-1}R$ for some $n \geq 1$.  This means that there exists some $s' \in S$ such that $s'r^n = 0$ in $R$.  Multiplying both sides of this last equation by $(s')^{n-1}$, we see that $s'r$ is nilpotent.  Thus $\frac{r}{s} = \frac{rs'}{ss'}$ with $ss' \in S$ and $rs' \in I$, so $\frac{r}{s} \in S^{-1}I$.